# PHP Documentor installed via PEAR, phpdoc Command Not Found

Tags: pear, phpdoc, php

I installed PHP Documentor on a shared host (Just Host) via PEAR and it appears to have installed correctly, no errors reported, and `phpdoc` is listed under the `bin` directory. Further, `phpDocumentor` is present under `php`, both of which reside in my Home folder at `/home/[user]/`.

I looked at `phpdoc` in the `bin` directory and everything points to the right places. I also followed the directions provided on my host's site and set my PHP include_path to `/home/[user]/php`. I have tried executing `phpdoc` from every location imagionable, including under `home/[user]/bin/` and I keep getting the following result:

```
    -bash-4.1$ phpdoc
    -bash: phpdoc: command not found
```

And here is the output from `$PATH` -

```
-bash-4.1$ echo $PATH
/home/[user]/perl5/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/home/[user]/perl5/bin:/ramdisk/php/54/bin:/usr/php/54/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The host is Linux, running PHP 5.4.10, Apache version 2.2.23.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to run phpdoc with the absolute path to the binary file: `/home/[user]/bin/phpdoc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the reply from my host's support rep again and tried their suggestion (what a concept) - it worked! Simply ran `~/bin/phpdoc` and voila.

If someone can explain why this worked and simply navigating to the same directory and entering `phpdoc` did not work, I'd appreciate it. Also, how might one make a link to that path so that `phpdoc` would work on its own?

Thanks!

Comment: If you enter a command in the shell, the interpreter looks in the `$PATH` if he can find a program with the name specified. The current directory is not part of the `$PATH`. Alternatively you can specify the while path to the executable, which always works (if the permissions are set correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh your path/environment after the installation using the following command:

```
phpenv rehash
```

Otherwise your new settings are not active in your current shell.

Comment: Sorry, week became hectic. The host replied to my support question and said that `phpdoc` is not run from the command line, which of course it is. I tried your suggestion and received `phpenv rehash command not found`